# How to get values of passed in object using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a following code

```
     public void ShowForm(String EName, String phoneNumber, String dnis, String mode, String callid)
    {

        objCallParams.EventName = EName;
        objCallParams.ANI = phoneNumber;
        objCallParams.DNIS = dnis;
        objCallParams.Mode = mode;
        objCallParams.CallId = callid;

        UIThreadContext.Post(InComing_Callback, (object)objCallParams);
    }
    private void InComing_Callback(object objCallParams)
    {
      /*want to access phone number i.e.objCallParams.ANI*/
    }
```

How do I access phoneNumber in InComing_Callback(object objCallParams) method?

Comment: What is the runtime type of `objCallParams`? (Ie. what would `objCallParams.GetType()` return?). You probably just need a case (but cannot be sure without knowing what `UIThreadContext` is and whether this is WebForms, WinForms, WPF or something else.

Comment: private FormParameters objCallParams = new FormParameters();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the type of the object you can use [casting](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx)

```
private void InComing_Callback(object objCallParams)
{
    // If you know that objCallParams will always be of the type FormParameters:
    var params = (FormParameters)objCallParams;

    // if you are not so sure about that
    var notSoSureParams = objCallParams as FormParameters;
    if (notSoSureParams != null)
    {

    }
}
```